# Using the lag function to find a moving average in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to find a moving average for the previous 12 rows. I need to have my result set look like this.

```
t   Year    Month   Sales   MovingAverage
1   2010      3      20     NULL
2   2010      4      22     NULL
3   2010      5      24     NULL
4   2010      6      25     NULL
5   2010      7      23     NULL
6   2010      8      26     NULL
7   2010      9      28     NULL
8   2010      10     26     NULL
9   2010      11     29     NULL
10  2010      12     27     NULL
11  2011      1      28     NULL
12  2011      2      30     NULL
13  2011      3      27     25.67
14  2011      4      29     26.25
15  2011      5      26     26.83
```

For row 13 I need to average rows 1 to 12 and have the result returned in row 13 column MovingAverage. Rows 1-12 have a MovingAverage of NULL because there should be at least 12 previous rows for the calculation. Rows t, Year, Month, and Sales already exist. I need to create the MovingAverage row. I am using postgreSQL but the syntax should be very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `lag()` function.  There is a build in moving average function.  Well, almost:

```
select t.*, avg(sales) over (order by t range between 12 preceding and current row
from table t;
```

The problem is that this will produce an average for the first 11 months.  To prevent that:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by t) >= 12
             then avg(sales) over (order by t range between 12 preceding and current row
        end) as MovingAvg
from table t;
```

Note that the syntax `rows between` instead of `range between` would be very similar for this query.

Comment: Instead of the second, you could also: `select t.*, avg(sales) over (order by t range between 12 preceding and 1 preceding) as MovingAvg
from table t;`

Comment: @SunnyPatel . . . The OP explicitly wants the values to be `NULL` if there are not 12 of them.  That is why this answer uses a `case` expression.