# Calculating a value based on a moving window of x previous rows in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table with the month, identifier and revenue for that month. What I would like to do is create a new field that for every row is the average revenue of the previous three months i.e. 'Prev_3month_Average'. Does anyone know a good sql function for this rather than joining the table onto itself three times?

E.g

```
    Month   ID  Revenue Prev_3month_Average
    201601  123 5       null
    201602  123 10      null
    201603  123 8       null
    201604  123 10      7.666666667
    201605  123 5       9.333333333
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: LAG() function may help:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021819/using-the-lag-function-to-find-a-moving-average-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL calculate moving average](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618353/t-sql-calculate-moving-average)